# How to add Iframe default content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I created a dynamically load page using iframe. When it load, it show empty space in the body area until i click page links. How to add default page when i frame load.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".divlink").click(function(){
     $("#content").attr("src" , $(this).attr("ref"));
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="content"></iframe>
    <a href="#" ref="page1.html" class="divlink" >Page 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" ref="page2.html" class="divlink" >Page 2</a><br />
    <a href="#" ref="page3.html" class="divlink" >Page 3</a><br />
    <a href="#" ref="page4.html" class="divlink" >Page 4</a><br />
    <a href="#" ref="page5.html" class="divlink" >Page 5</a><br />
    <a href="#" ref="page6.html" class="divlink" >Page 6</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to show page content for the first page content?

Comment: Yes.when it load, i want to show a page. now it show as blank

Comment: So why not just setting iframe src to first link `ref`?!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet. In this case it will load page from the first 'a' element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").attr("src" , $("a.divlink:first").attr("ref"));
    $(".divlink").click(function(){
         $("#content").attr("src" , $(this).attr("ref"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the iframe `src` property

`<iframe id="content" src="page1.html"></iframe>`